# Measuring Internal Network Speed/Bandwidth in Java

Tags: java, networking, bandwidth

I need to be able to monitor the speed of my internal network using java. I was thinking I could use a two part system with a server and a client. I do not need need response time such as what is generated with ping but and actual speed in mbps for upload and download.

My idea would be to have the Server send a packet or series of packets to the client which then replies and then the Server would calculate the speed of the network between those two points. Does anyone have any idea how I could implement this?

Thank You ahead of time.

Comment: If you don't want actual speed, then what precisely are you measuring?  Are you concerned about upload and download?

Comment: exactly upload and dowload speeds across two points on the network

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, an interesting problem.  I hope you like reading... :-)

I'd be interested to know how the monitoring tool would be used.  At
work, the sysadmins just have a couple of large screens in the room,
showing a webpage containing loads of network stats, with it constantly
updating.

The rest of my description assumes the network monitoring tool would be
used as described above.  If you just want to be able to do an ad-hoc
test between two random hosts on your network, I'd just use rsync to
transfer a reasonably large file (about 1 - 2MB).  I'm sure there are
other file transfer tools that calculate the transfer speed too.

When implementing this, (especially within a large network) you *must*
minimise the risk that the test floods the network, hampering the people
(or programs) actually using it.  You don't want to be blamed for a
massive slowdown (or worse, an outage) just because you were conducting
a test.  Your sysadmins won't thank you...

I'd architect the tool in the following way:

1. Bob is a server which participates in an individual 'test' by doing
   the following:

   1. Bob receives a request from a client.  The request states how much data the client is about to send.
   2. If the amount of data proposed to be sent is not too large, wait for the data.  Otherwise Bob rejects the request immediately and ends the communication.
   3. Once the required number of bytes has been received, reply with the amount of time it took to receive it all.  Bob terminates the communication.
2. Alice is the component that displays the result of the measurements
   taken (via a webpage or otherwise).  Alice is a long lived process
   (maybe a web server), configured to periodically connect to a list of
   Bob servers.  For each configured Bob:

   1. Send Bob a request with the amount of data Alice is about to
      send.
   2. Send Bob the specified amount of data, as fast as possible.
   3. Await the reply from Bob, and compute the network speed.
   4. 'Display' the result for this instance of Bob.  You may choose
      to display an aggregate result.  For example, the average result for
      each of the last 20 tests, to iron out any anomalies...
3. When conducting a given test, Alice should report any failures.  E.g.
   'a TCP connection could not be established with Bob', or 'Bob
   prematurely terminated the transfer' or whatever else...
4. Scatter Bob servers to strategic locations in your (possibly large)
   network, and configure Alice to go them.  For each instance of Bob, you
   should configure

   1. The time interval in between tests.
   2. The 'leeway' (I'll explain this in a bit).
   3. The amount of data to send to Bob for each test.
   4. Bob's address (duh).
5. You want to 'stagger' the tests that a given Alice will attempt.  You
   don't want Alice to trigger the test to all Bob servers at once, thereby
   flooding your network, possibly giving skewed results and so forth.
   Allow the test to occur at a *randomised* time in the future.  For
   example, if the test interval is every 10 minutes, configure a 'leeway'
   of 1 minute, meaning the next test might occur anywhere between 9 and 11
   minutes' time.
6. If there is to be more than one Alice running at a time, the total
   number of instances should be small.  The more Alices you have, the more
   you interfere with the network.  Again, you don't want to be responsible
   for an outage.
7. The amount of data Alice should send in an individual test should be
   small.  500KB?  You probably want a given test to run for no more than
   10 seconds.  Maybe get Bob to timeout if the test takes too long.

I've deliberately omitted the transport to use (TCP, UDP, whatever)
because you'll get issues depending on the transport, and I don't know
how you want to handle those issues.  For example, you'd have to
consider how to handle dropped datagrams with UDP.  What result would
you compute?  You don't get this issue with TCP, because it
automatically retransmits dropped packets.  With TCP, your
throughput will be artificially low if the two endpoints
are far away from each other.  Here's some
[info](http://bradhedlund.com/2008/12/19/how-to-calculate-tcp-throughput-for-long-distance-links/) on it.

If you had the patience to read this far, I hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than writing a server you might want to just use tomcat or apache to be the server, then you just have the client upload a file of a specific size, and measure the time, then turn around and download the file, to measure the download speed.

You could write your own server to do this, but you would be basically doing what has been done many times before, then you will need to ensure your server isn't skewing the numbers.

Comment: I was thinking of that originally but I need it to be in java because it needs to be able to plugin to my network monitoring program which is written in java

Comment: Your network monitoring program is the client, it sends data to a webserver and then retrieves it.  The server can be in any language, as you just need a server that will allow you to easily upload and then download a file.

Comment: yes I understand that but how would I calculate the speed. Lets say I send a packet that is 1024 bytes to the client from the monitoring program. Would the programs have to get a timestamp and then calculate  the speed if so how would i do that? How would I get an accurate timestamp?

Comment: As soon as the file is received send out two UDP packets, immediately. Most likely both will get through, but UDP is faster than TCP, so the response will be quick.  If you upload a 1M file then the slowdown due for the response will be minimized.